# Number of seconds until every 20 minutes

Tags: php

For a game I'm making, each turn is at :00, :20, and :40 past the hour. I am trying to create a countdown that will display the number of minutes (and eventually seconds) to the next turn.

My current approach is to store the time of the next turn in a database, then doing

```
$time = time() - $time_to_turn
```

where `time_to_turn` is the database entry of the next turn time.

Is there a way to not use the database?

Comment: How many systems are involved? If several systems, can you rely on their clocks being synchronized?

Comment: Well the turns take place on the server at the specified times, the time until the next turn depends on the user's clock (which has no effect on turns taking place)

Comment: So, if it depends on the user's clock, it depends on the user's timezone? ie, the timezone of the server is not necessarily the same as the timezone of the user?

Comment: Not particularly, just every 20 minutes

Answer (score 2):

Try `$minutesRemaining = 20 - date('i') % 20;` or `$secondsRemaining = 1200 - date('s') % 1200`